# CheckBox ui is not updated though the item value of checkbox is updated, Getx flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, checkbox, state, flutter-getx

[image]

*Get the working code sample [here](https://github.com/1Krishna16/Desktop/tree/master/app)*

I have an `RxList` of `addOnProducts` which contains `product` and `selected` attributes.

I am trying to implement the simple multiSelectable grid View, but on clicking the checkBox the selected attribute changes but it is not reflected back to the ui,
If i refresh it will be updated.

I tried Obx()=> (); widget , It is still not updating

My ProductController

```
class ProductsController extends GetxController {
  late Worker worker;
  static ProductsController instance = Get.find();
  RxList<ProductModel> products = RxList<ProductModel>([]);
  RxList<CheckProduct> addOnProducts = <CheckProduct>[].obs;
  String collection = "products";
  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    products.bindStream(getAllProducts());
    worker = once(products, (List<ProductModel> value) {
      fillAddOnProducts(value);
    }, condition: () => products.isNotEmpty);
  }


  Stream<List<ProductModel>> getAllProducts() => FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(collection)
      .snapshots()
      .map((query) => query.docs
          .map((item) => ProductModel.fromMap(item.data(), item.id))
          .toList());
 
  void fillAddOnProducts(List<ProductModel> products) => {
        products.forEach((element) {
          addOnProducts.add(CheckProduct(product: element, selected: false));
        })
      };
}

class CheckProduct {
  ProductModel product;
  bool selected;
  CheckProduct(
      {required ProductModel this.product, required bool this.selected});
}
```

My Grid View

```
class AddOns extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddOns({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [],
          title: Text("Select Addons"),
        ),
        body: Obx(() => GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              children: productsController.addOnProducts
                  .map((element) => ProductWidget(product: element))
                  .toList(),
            )));
  }
}

class ProductWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final CheckProduct product;
  const ProductWidget({Key? key, required this.product}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 4,
              left: 4,
              child: Checkbox(
                value: product.selected,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  print("value of the value is : $value");
                  print("value of product selected before is: " +
                      product.selected.toString());
                  product.selected = value!;
                  print("value of product selected after is: " +
                      product.selected.toString());
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Therefore in the console it is :

```
I/flutter (20067): value of the value is : true
I/flutter (20067): value of product selected before is: false
I/flutter (20067): value of product selected after is: true
```

But the checkBox is not updating, it updates only when i refresh, How to overCome this? Adding Obx() to the parent isn't helping..

Find the github link to code below [here](https://github.com/1Krishna16/Desktop/tree/master/app) which has just the question and and the problem faced..

Comment: Yes the value changes but the problem is it is a stateless widget. You have to make the selected value observable and only then if you use OBX in checkbox widget, your widget will be updated. You did not post a reproduce-able code that I can just copy paste and run and fix it for you. You can just try it and get back to me

Comment: I converted into a statefull widget, and by saying to make the selected value observable , do you mean, in CheckProduct class the bool selected should be made bool selected.obs?

Comment: First answer me this. Are you using controller for Product Widget class? I meant instead of calling final CheckProduct product; inside your productwidget class, you need to do it like this: final product = Rxn<CheckProduct>(); and you have to have it in your controller class. Next, wrap your CheckBox with OBX(). This should fix it

Comment: https://github.com/1Krishna16/Desktop/tree/master/app Please open this link, As you said that you could have helped if it were a reproduceable code. I created a reproduceable code . Thank you

Comment: An added explanation ,would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin , Can i reach you ?

Comment: OK. I have fixed it for you. Please check Answer after a while. In GetX it is not important to pass object. You can just call your controller class in anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through your code. I've implemented the following that will change state without hot reload:

In your main dart you do not need to put your product controller here as you are not using it

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'grid.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: GridSelect(),
    );
  }
}
```

Next, I have changed your grid class to generate a list of product widget as the size of the addProduct list length. In my opinion this is a better way to write GridView counts children. Remove obx from your gridview and change your stateful widget to stateless as you are using Getx. It will manage your state even in a stateless widget. Add your product controller here as you will access addProduct list from the controller class.

**grid.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:test_project/controllers/productController.dart';
import 'package:test_project/productWidget.dart';

class GridSelect extends StatelessWidget {
  final _controller = Get.put(ProductController());
  GridSelect({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: List.generate(_controller.addOnProducts.length, (index) => ProductWidget(index: index))
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In your product controller class, remove the instance as it is not important. That is the only change here:

**ProductController.dart**

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:test_project/models/productModel.dart';

class ProductController extends GetxController {
  RxList<CheckProduct> addOnProducts = <CheckProduct>[].obs;

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    addOnProducts.add(CheckProduct(product: ProductModel('productOne', 20)));
    addOnProducts.add(CheckProduct(product: ProductModel('productTwo', 25)));
    addOnProducts.add(CheckProduct(product: ProductModel('productThree', 30)));
    addOnProducts.add(CheckProduct(product: ProductModel('productFour', 40)));
  }
}

class CheckProduct {
  ProductModel product;
  RxBool selected = false.obs;
  CheckProduct({
    required this.product,
  });
}
```

Lastly, your productWidget class needs a required value index. So, the widget knows which index in gridview the user is clicking and use Obx() here in checkbox as you have an observable value selected here. Remember to always use Obx() when you have an obs value. This will update the widget whenever an obs value changes. Here, if you notice we are using Get.find() instead of Put as Get.put is already inside the scope so all you need to do is find the controller that you will use. You can find or put multiple controllers and update values as much as you want.

**productWidget.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:test_project/controllers/productController.dart';

class ProductWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final ProductController _controller = Get.find();
  final int index;
  ProductWidget({Key? key, required this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 4,
            left: 4,
            child: Obx(()=>Checkbox(
              value: _controller.addOnProducts[index].selected.value,
              onChanged: (value) {
                print("value of the value is : $value");
                print("value of product selected before is: " +
                    _controller.addOnProducts[index].selected.toString());
                _controller.addOnProducts[index].selected.value = value!;
                print("value of product selected after is: " +
                    _controller.addOnProducts[index].selected.toString());
              },
            )),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Go through GetX documentation for proper use of GetX. Even though I have 2 apps in Playstore with GetX, I still go through documentation from time to time. They have a clear documentation on how to manage state.

Comment: Thank you @Md.Kamrul Amin, But may i know when i mapped every element from GridSelect() to productWidget() why was the parent element not getting updated . Why is that it was just a copy , soo it didn't alter the parent? or it did alter the parent but i didn't place Obx() in the right place ? what was the reason ? using [index] or Placing obx() in the proper place ? Thank you anyways

Comment: You can obviously use map and pass element like you did. But instead of passing the whole element it is always better to pass just the index. The reason you parent widget was not updated because your gridview had no reactive variable. It was just calling your ProductWidget. So, no your obx was not placed in the right place as your widget that has the obx value is a completely seperate class. So, remember use OBX when you are sure which widget state you need to change. In your case, you did not need to change the gridview, instead your checkbox needed to be updated only.

Answer (score 0):

In ProductWidget adding an additional Obx() solved my problem

```
class ProductWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final CheckProduct product;
  const ProductWidget({Key? key, required this.product}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 4,
              left: 4,
             // Even the child needs Obx() ; The parent's Obx() is not reflected here
              child: Obx(()=>(Checkbox( 
                value: product.selected,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  print("value of the value is : $value");
                  print("value of product selected before is: " +
                      product.selected.toString());
                  product.selected = value!;
                  print("value of product selected after is: " +
                      product.selected.toString());
                },
              ),))
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
```